# Uploading comments to firebase database with swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload comments into posts so that my database structure looks like the one in the screenshot, my download function works to download the comments but I'm not sure how to create a function to upload them to the appropriate post. If I pass through the postID could I upload comments using that?

```
func uploadMessage(withContent content: String, withIcon icon: String, withColor color: String, withDate date: String, withuserName userName: String,sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()){
        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["content" : content, "color" : color, "icon" : icon, "date" : date, "userName" : userName])
        sendComplete(true)
    }


func getFeedMessages(handler: @escaping (_ feedMessages:[FeedMessages]) -> ()){
        var feedMessagesArray = [FeedMessages]()
        var commentArray = [messageComments]()


        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (feedMessagesSnapshot) in

            guard let feedMessagesSnapshot = feedMessagesSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
            for messages in feedMessagesSnapshot {

                let content = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as? String ?? "Joe Flacco is an elite QB"
                let icon = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "icon").value as? String ?? "none"
                var color = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "color").value as? String ?? "bop"
                let date = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "date").value as? String ?? "0"
                let userName = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "userName").value as? String ?? "Anonymous"

                let comments = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments").value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]


                for comment in comments {

                    let theComment = comment.value as? [String: Any]

                    let theContent = theComment?["content"] as? String ?? ""
                    let theIcon = theComment?["icon"] as? String ?? ""
                    let theColor = theComment?["color"] as? String ?? ""
                    let theDate = theComment?["date"] as? String ?? ""
                    let theName = theComment?["userName"] as? String ?? ""

                    let aComment = messageComments(content: theContent, color: theColor, icon: theIcon, date: theDate,  userName: theName)
                    commentArray.append(aComment)
                }

                let messages = FeedMessages(content: content, color: color, icon: icon, date: date, comments: commentArray, userName: userName)
                feedMessagesArray.append(messages)
            }

            handler(feedMessagesArray)
        }
    }
```

[image: database structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution, you need the key of the comment

```
func uploadComment(withContent content: String, withIcon icon: String, withColor color: String, withDate date: String, withUserName userName: String, withKey key: String, sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()){
        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.child(key).child("comments").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["content" : content, "color" : color, "icon" : icon, "date" : date, "userName" : userName])
        sendComplete(true)
    }
```